# Delete documents in batch mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, batch-processing, bulk

I have a list of more than 2 million large documents, each document has size on an average of 280kb - 350kb.

I want to delete documents on specific query.

I was trying `deleteMany` using a primary key, but it was not able to delete all the documents and it slows down the collection as well.

I tried this:

```
db.texts.deleteMany({projectId:"projectId"});
```

and `projectId` is also indexed.

After that I took another approach of `bulk.find.remove()` as well. It was also not helping.

I was trying in nodejs like below.

```
const bulk = await db.texts.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({projectId: "projectId"}).remove();
bulk.execute();
```

Is there any way where I can delete in batch with slowing down the collection. Let's say for each `projectId` I have average of 30,000 documents.